# Развивается ли СУБД Access?

Tags: sql, access, office

Например, Microsoft при новых версиях MS SQL Server говорит, что стоимость запросов уменьшается, производительность повышается и все такое(т.е все круто), а про новые Access ничего подобного не встречал.

Собственно вопрос, а идет ли какое-либо развитие в плане производительности в СУБД Access или нет?

Мне довелось использовать  2007,2013,2016 и как стопорились они на запросах, которые проглатывает на ура MS SQL так и стопорятся.

Мне кажется, что в Access до сих пор не задействует потенциал многоядерных процессоров.

Даже допустимый размер БД с 2гб не повышают.

Answer (score 9):

Access - это SOHO - решение - для дома и МАЛОГО офиса, оно не предназначено для поддержки огромных баз. А раз так, то и вкладывать в него усилия R&D нет смысла.

Comment: Ну должны же MS привлекать к своему продукту людей. Я смотрю на последние офисы и кроме изменения интерфейса я не вижу действительно полезных фич...

Comment: Access это в некотором роде legacy продукт, который тащат в новые версии пакета Офис, чтобы не упустить клиента. И впарить ему новую версию Office. Те люди, которые программируют на access, на самом деле устраивают жуткую подставу эксплуатационщикам. Лучше переходить на альтернативы типа msde или sqlite

Comment: @gecube "подстава" для эксплуатации начинается с момента завязывания форточки в серверные процессы.

Comment: @gecube, у Access много +. Например, многие вещи доступны из коробки, дружелюбный интерфейс для незнакомых с SQL пользователями, можно недостающий функционал на коленке сделать. Так как интерфейс дружелюбный, то редко требуется пилить интерфейс для взаимодействия пользователя с бд.

Comment: @gbg для access есть сфера применения - некие локальные базы на предприятии, с возможностью отчетов, причем которые может поправить пользователь без особых навыков программирования. Результат в конечном счёте всегда плохой ))) но какое - то время система работает дешево и сердито )))

Comment: @iluxa1810 согласен, про то же и говорю. Но если это все помножить на стоимость лицензии access (~10 т.р.) против бесплатного msde, то все на самом деле печально (((

Comment: @gecube, а аналогов Access нету? Что бы был дружелюбный интерфейс и все такое.

Comment: @iluxa1810 libreoffbice base ?

Answer (score 6):

Думаю что вы правы и как СУБД MS Access не развивается уже лет 10.

Но и собственно зачем его развивать?
Движение идёт в сторону мобильных, где в качестве БД есть MS SQL Compact.
Другое направление развития -- это веб-приложения, но там по части БД довольно широкий выбор.

Вот документ, в котором Jet 4.0 объявляется устаревшим: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810810.aspx

Comment: Вроде, новые Access работают через ACE 12.0.